# remove "$" in xml with stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, translate

I have all sorts of ways to remove the "$" under the "statValue1" node and no luck. Can someone help me with the stylsheet.

If you see below some of the source XML, I need to remove the $ from all of the statTitle1's

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/davidhe/Documents/Altova/XMLSpy2016/Examples/stats.xml"?>
<tours>
    <tour tourCodeLC="s" tourCodeUC="S" tourName="Group!A>
        <years>
            <year year="2016">
                <lastTrnProc trnName="Through Week Ending: 02/29/2016" permNum="000" trnNum="032" endDate="Feb 28, 2016"/>
                <stats>
                    <stat statID="109" cat="1" rndOrEvt="Events">
                        <statName>Money List</statName>
                        <explanation>
The total official money a player has earned year-to-date. (109)
</explanation>
                        <tourAvg>$51,906</tourAvg>
                        <statTitles numOfStatTitles="3">
                            <statTitle1>Money</statTitle1>
                            <statTitle2/>
                            <statTitle3>YTD Victories</statTitle3>
                            <statTitle4/>
                            <statTitle5>Money Behind Lead</statTitle5>
                        </statTitles>
                        <details>
                            <plr plrNum="01666">
                                <plrName>
                                    <last>Smith</last>
                                    <first>Brad</first>
                                    <middle/>
                                    <nickname/>
                                </plrName>
                                <statValues>
                                    <rndEvents>3</rndEvents>
                                    <statValue1>
                                        $333,850</statValue1>
                                    <statValue2/>
                                    <statValue3>1</statValue3>
                                    <statValue4/>
                                    <statValue5/>
                                </statValues>
                                <curRank tied="">1</curRank>
                                <prevRank tied="">1</prevRank>
                            </plr>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="translate(//tours/tour/years/year/stats/stat/details/plr[1]/statValues/st‌​atValue1, '*\%!@$&amp;', '')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: use a combination of `starts-with()` and `substring()`. Remember that the first character in xslt has index 1 and not 0.

Comment: this is what i have...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="translate(//tours/tour/years/year/stats/stat/details/plr[1]/statValues/statValue1, '*\%!@$&amp;', '')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="statValues/st‌​atValue1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '$', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of the second template you have.

Comment: you should use `match="statValues/*"` instead

Comment: @MatthewWhited, you are right, I got lost in the long path in the comment and picked the wrong pattern, now corrected.

Comment: Maybe I have this wrong but here is what I have and it still does not work.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="statValues/st‌​atValue1">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '$', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Matt, thanks for the help...looks like I'm almost there but the new stylesheet is removing the "statValues" node...

Comment: Make sure you keep the first template you had, that is necessary too.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="statValues">
  <xsl:for-each select="*" >
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '$', '')"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: now shows: <plr plrNum="01666">
<plrName>
<last>Langer</last>
<first>Bernhard</first>
<middle/>
<nickname/>
</plrName>
<rndEvents>3</rndEvents>
<statValue1>333,850</statValue1>
<statValue2/>
<statValue3>1</statValue3>
<statValue4/>
<statValue5/>
<curRank tied="">1</curRank>
<prevRank tied="">1</prevRank>
</plr>

Answer (score 0):

since you are using differnet names for the  child elements you will need to be a little more generic.

```
<xsl:template match="statValues">
  <xsl:for-each select="*" >
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '$', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```